# Execute from Child Multiple Times

Tags: c

So I am executing a file with execv() inside a child process with its file descriptors possibly being modified based on the input.

However, I am trying to execute one process after the next from the child, but because execv() takes over the child process, calling execv() after the previous call doesnt work.

How would I go about executing multiple processes from a single child?

Comment: have the child spawn a grandchild, have the grandchild run exec, have the child wait for it, spawn another grandchild, etc..

Comment: I tried that, but because I am using pipes/fd's nothing gets output when run from the grandchild, only the child.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `execv` in a process, then the original process image is overwritten with the a new one from the program you are executing. That means that you can not run multiple `execv`'s in the same process, as only the first one will ever get executed.

To get around this, you have to spawn a new process for each `execv` you plan to run.